# String interpolation in Styled components breaks linter

Tags: css, string, emotion

interpolating "theme" variables or any sort of string interoplation in styled components breaks the linter flow and I can format the css anymore. Any ideas on how to solve it? The linter breaks the line on formatting and this generates the problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 700px) and (orientation: portrait) {
.innerModal {
  .modalContentContainer {
   min-height: 270px;
    width: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 0.1fr 1fr 0.5fr 1fr;
    padding: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing.m} ${({ theme }) =>
```

theme.spacing.xs};